# Swapping out ListView Grid in XAML/Xamarin (Two grid versions, single code behind)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a button that toggles between a list and tile view of some items. The code behind is identical for both and the only difference is the size of what is displayed and the properties. Currently I have the list view implemented and the XAML looks like this:

```
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="FilesListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
              ItemSelected="FileItemSelected">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding IsFolder, Converter={StaticResource fileTypeToImageConverter}}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource pathToFilenameConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ModifiedDate, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource fileSizeConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
```

This is a partial view; the FileBrowser control gets nested in another stack layout that contains the toggle button. The button is defined in XAML like this:

```
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Toggle View" Order="Primary" Icon="{Binding ViewIcon}" Command="{Binding ToggleViewCommand}"/>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

where ToggleViewCommand is:

```
    protected void ToggleView()
    {
        FileBrowserControl.ToggleView();
        ViewModel.ToggleViewIcon();
    }
```

I need help figuring out how to implement `FileBrowserControl.ToggleView();`. I need to either dynamically swap out the grid XAML with a different XAML snippet (representing the tile view), or update the grid in code. The first option seems easier in terms of defining what the tile view would look like, but I don't want to duplicate the code behind logic by creating FileBrowserXaml.xaml/FileBrowserXaml.xaml.cs which would have the same code behind logic as FileBrowser.xaml.cs. What is the Xamarin best practice for what I'm trying to do?

(As a side note, this needs to be cross platform.)

---

**Update:** I decided to try to build the data template in code. I have this so far:

```
    public void ToggleView()
    {
        DataTemplate itemTemplate;
        if (_view == FileBrowserView.List)
        {
            itemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var cell = new ViewCell();
                var grid = new Grid();

                // Define columns
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });

                // Define rows
                var image = new Image
                {
                    WidthRequest = 40,
                    HeightRequest = 40,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                };
                image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
                                 new Binding("IsFolder", BindingMode.Default, new FileTypeToImageValueConverter()));
                grid.Children.Add(image, 0, 0);

                var pathLabel = new Label {HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand};
                pathLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,
                                     new Binding("Path", BindingMode.Default, new PathToFilenameValueConverter()));
                grid.Children.Add(pathLabel, 1, 0);

                var dateLabel = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };
                dateLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,
                                     new Binding("ModifiedDate", BindingMode.Default, new DateTimeDisplayValueConverter()));
                grid.Children.Add(dateLabel, 2, 0);

                var sizeLabel = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand };
                dateLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,
                                     new Binding("Size", BindingMode.Default, new FileSizeDisplayValueConverter()));
                grid.Children.Add(sizeLabel, 3, 0);

                cell.View = grid;
                return cell;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            itemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var cell = new ViewCell();
                var grid = new Grid();

                // Define columns
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});

                // Define rows
                var image = new Image
                {
                    WidthRequest = 80,
                    HeightRequest = 80,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                };
                image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
                                 new Binding("IsFolder", BindingMode.Default, new FileTypeToImageValueConverter()));
                grid.Children.Add(image, 0, 0);

                var pathLabel = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
                pathLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,
                                     new Binding("Path", BindingMode.Default, new PathToFilenameValueConverter()));
                grid.Children.Add(pathLabel, 0, 1);

                cell.View = grid;
                return cell;
            });
        }
        FilesListView.ItemTemplate = itemTemplate;
    }
```

The issue I am having now is, in the tile view, every item is on its own row. I want them to wrap (the path should be underneath the image, but each path/image combo should be side-by-side with the next one, like in Windows Explorer or in a typical app launcher). What is the best way to build a data template to achieve this? Is a grid the correct template to use or is there a better one?

Comment: A grid sounds like the correct template to use to achieve what you described (A tile view). Are you creating more than one column in the GridView to put your items into and adding your items into all the available columns? 
*note: this approach will require some bookkeeping in terms of adding items to the grid.

Comment: Can you draw what you want to achieve? BTW: you can also use DateTemplateSelector for multiple DataTemplates: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/66502/#Comment_66502

Comment: You can probably (and *should*) keep UI declarative in XAML. You can define Page or View-level resources and then look for the resource in code, rather than have the whole implementation. This much UI defined in code is ugly, especially if other parts of your app are using XAML for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ResourceDictionary and StaticResource?

I am thinking you may be able to accomplish what you want by having the ListView ItemTemplate set to a StaticResource and then having the toggle button switch out which one is used for the view.

Below is kind of what I am thinking of:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>

          <DataTemplate x:Key="TileViewTemplate">
             <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                   <!-- the layout of your template here -->
                </ViewCell.View>
             </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>

          <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
             <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                   <!-- the layout of your template here -->
                </ViewCell.View>
             </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>

       </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

 <ListView x:Name="FilesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" 
           ItemsSelected="FileItemSelected"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileViewTemplate}"/>

</ContentPage>
```

And then, the toggleview command could switch the ItemTemplate property. This way you are not having to worry about two ListViews - and it can keep the XAML a bit more manageable.

Just a thought, but the ResourceDictionary has really been helpful for me.